# SQL problem: Calculating avg days between sessions by user type

Tags: mysql, sql

**Let's say I have the following 2 tables**

**Table 1: User roles**

| User_ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | EE |
| 3 | Contractor |
| 5 | Admin |

**Table 2: User Sessions**

| User_ID | Session_ID | Session_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 9 | 2021-01-02 |
| 3 | 10 | 2021-01-03 |
| 5 | 11 | 2021-01-04 |
| 5 | 12 | 2021-01-05 |

**Desired Outcome:**

| User Type | AVG days between login |
| --- | --- |
| Admin | 50 |
| EE | 35 |
| CR | 100 |
| Accountant | 10 |

Can anyone help me get to avg days between sessions by user type?

Comment: how can accountant have 10 when session hasn't his id and when we are at it which mysql version? 5 or 8

Comment: Hi, thx for the call out fixed the theoretical table. using latest version of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/welcome.html

Comment: if you use mysql 8 use can use th window funczion lag  to get the difference between to dates and you link in can not use, besides hat is is forbidden here make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

some ways would think of doing:

1. select from user_sessions table ordering by user_id asc & session_created_at desc, where create column that is row number partioned over user_id. lets call this table ordered_sessions
2. join table #1 against itself such that row_num = row_num+1 AND user_id = user_id. to get a table with columns of user_session and other column that is corresponding previous day of user.
3. use some datediff function (example [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) against the two session_created_at columns in table #2 to get days diference
4. join table #3 against user_roles table ON user_id
5. average over column from #3 group by user_type.Type

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 You can use the window function LAG, to get the difference between two login Dates

> ```
> CREATE TABLE User_roles (
>   `User_ID` INTEGER,
>   `Type` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO User_roles
>   (`User_ID`, `Type`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Admin'),
>   ('2', 'EE'),
>   ('3', 'Contractor'),
>   ('5', 'Admin');
>
> CREATE TABLE User_Sessions (
>   `User_ID` INTEGER,
>   `Session_ID` INTEGER,
>   `Session_created_at` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO User_Sessions
>   (`User_ID`, `Session_ID`, `Session_created_at`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '8', '2021-01-01'),
>   ('1', '9', '2021-01-02')
>   ,
>   ('1', '18', '2021-01-20'),
>   ('3', '10', '2021-01-03'),
>   ('5', '11', '2021-01-04'),
>   ('5', '12', '2021-01-05')
>   ,
>   ('5', '13', '2021-01-10');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Type` as 'User Type',
> AVG(diff_days ) As 'AVG days between login'
> FROM (SELECT ur.`User_ID`, ur.`Type`,
> timestampdiff(DAY, lag(us.`Session_created_at`, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY us.`User_ID` ORDER BY us.`Session_ID` ASC), us.`Session_created_at`) as diff_days 
> FROM 
> User_Sessions us JOIN User_roles ur ON us.User_ID = ur.User_ID) t1
> WHERE diff_days IS NOT NULL
> GROUP BY `User_ID`,`Type`
> ORDER BY `User_ID` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> User Type | AVG days between login
> :-------- | ---------------------:
> Admin     |                 9.5000
> Admin     |                 3.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0fcd8d72925ca1bbfb076f150e05be5)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-`join` to find the login/logout sessions for each `user_id`, and then `join` your roles table back onto the result, computing the average while grouping on the role type:

```
with cte(id, sid, sc1, sc2) as (
   select s.user_id, s.session_id, s.session_created_at, min(s1.session_created_at) from sessions s 
   left join sessions s1 on s.user_id = s1.user_id and s1.session_created_at > s.session_created_at
   group by s.user_id, s.session_id, s.session_created_at
)
select r.`type`, avg(c.sc2 - c.sc1) from cte c 
left join roles r on c.id = r.user_id where c.sc1 is not null group by r.`type`
```